# PCI bus error on startup while booting into login screen (Kubuntu 16.04)

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 16.04, pci

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 on this PC
(http://www.hpshopping.in/HP_Pavilion_Notebook_-_15-ab549tx).

The problem that I am facing is:

On startup this shows up before the login screen:

[image: Screenshot]

At times it is just stops at this screen and doesn't move to the login screen. Or while it shuts down it stops 
at this screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related to the wifi adapter and 6th gen intel processors. Several new notebooks have reported such issue.

Use this link ( [about the adding paramter to kernel here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)) to understand about adding kernel boot paramter temporarily and making it permanent.
Then,

Add the parameter ,   `pci=nomsi`

And reboot.

If the problem is solved then make the change permanent. 
If does not work then try,

`pci=noaer`

same way and make it permanent if this works.

(*Reason for appearance is  related to the recent Intel Skylake architecture CPUs and Realtek rtl8723be wireless adaptor.

The ubuntu team knows about it. Read more here [Bug_track_ubuntu_PCIe bus error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173)  )

Comment: is there  any difference between the two `pci=nomsi` & `pci=noaer`? I tried `pci=nomsi` which works but makes my PC boot very slow close to 2mins 15 secs

Comment: @Abhishek :   I do not know the difference. Sorry. 2 mins is a long time !

Comment: The error is still there http://paste.ubuntu.com/16556672/ . I guess it just doesn't output it.

Comment: oh ! seems like this is a serious bug

Comment: don't forget to "sudo update-grub".